Ubuntu Repository sites using https or port 443
can please advise if there is any other site apart from archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
that uses https instead of http
as i need to download ubuntu and security updates under port 443
as port 80 is blocked as it is less secure ...
appreciate your assistance community
Thanks

This list of Ubuntu mirrors details which ones support https.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors
For example, this mirror in the United States
https://mirror.enzu.com/ubuntu/

Or this mirror in Germany
https://mirror.dogado.de/ubuntu/

There are lots more.  It looks like around half of mirrors support https.
